# x.690 universal class tags implementation reference

Tags: certificates, x.509

Can anyone with enough knowledge of [X.690](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690) tell me where can I find the official reference implementation for the universal class tags for X.690. (For example: For TLS we can reference RFC 5246.) When I look at [line 565](https://github.com/jruby/jruby-openssl/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jruby/ext/openssl/ASN1.java#L565) and the lines after it, that makes me wonder how do they know the correct way to implement, let's say `T-61String`.

I've been trying to find the open source implementation of `EMBEDDED-PDV (11)`, `Relative-OID (13)` and `Character-String (29)`. Tried looking at bouncy castle but nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I've found it. The link below are for those who might need it:

1. http://www.oss.com/asn1/dubuisson.html
2. http://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-X.690-200811-S!!PDF-E&type=items